# Read a file from line X to line Y?

Tags: php, file, offset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I open a file from line X to line Y in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514673/how-do-i-open-a-file-from-line-x-to-line-y-in-php)

Is there a way to read a file in PHP5 from line X to line Y into a string, without reading the entire file.

I would like to return huge files (10,000+ lines) using ajax requests. Each request will provide the client with additional lines. And due to the fact that the file can reach large sizes, I would like to avoid reading it whole over and over again.

Thank you.