# Replace region in txt file using PHP

Tags: php, file

I have a text file named Notifications.txt. It contains certain groups of contents. Each group begins with a `<grouptitle>` tag and ends with a `</grouptitle>` tag {grouptitle changes> 
For example here is a sample contents

```
<schedule> New schedule for Mathematics 307 has been emailed to students </schedule>
<convocation> The convocation of 34th batch will be on may 3rd </convocation
```

Now I want to delete the data in from `<schedule>` to `</schedule>` including the tags using a php website.

How can I do this? And I'm a little short on time so would appreciate if you guys can post a sample code as well

Thanks a ton

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/3004080/973578

Comment: That sounds like XML. You can either parse the file with something like SimpleXML or strip out the contents with preg_replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do so by replacing the tags and it's contents with regular expressions:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('path/to/file/Notifications.txt');
$contents = preg_replace("!<schedule>.*?</schedule>\r?\n!s", '', $contents);
file_put_contents('path/to/file/Notifications.txt', $contents);
```

Comment: @7ochemThanks man.. That worked like a charm.:) kudos