# Clear the row using the line number and replace it with the given value

Tags: php

In the following text file (file.txt):

```
1 Hello!
2 How
3 and
4 you?
```

I would like to replace line 3 with the following statement:

```
3 are
```

Do you have a solution to find the line number and replace it with the specified value?
Of course, without the use of a FENDER or REPLACE for word.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I've already tried finding the word. But that word may change later. I didn't find anything for the idea I came up with.

Comment: Have a look at [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php).

Comment: What about using explode with CR or LF character ?

Comment: Hello Flyzzx! Can you give any more explanation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to replace a particular line in a text file using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004041/how-to-replace-a-particular-line-in-a-text-file-using-php)

Comment: There are so many duplicates of this here on SO, please try searching before posting a new question.  If your case is different, reference the answers you've tried and describe why yours is different or doesn't work.