# How to read big file by 100 lines?

Tags: php

I have a rather big .txt file (~220Mb) and I need to read it by 100 lines (\n symbol) chunks (for example). How can I do it using php?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I open a file from line X to line Y in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514673/how-do-i-open-a-file-from-line-x-to-line-y-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

`fopen` and `fgets`. The [fgets manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) has an example on reading a file line-by-line without loading it into memory all at once.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fp = open('big_text_file.txt',"r");
if($fp){
    $c = 0;
    $data = array();
    while(!feof($fp)){
        if($c == 100){
            $c = 0;
            // Do whatever it is you want here
            unset($data);
            $data = array();
        }
        $data[] = fgets($fp,4096);        
        $c++;
    }
    if($c > 0){
        // Do whatever you need to again
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```