# Reversing A text file using PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I have a file that is sorted using natsort()...(In ascending order)

But actually i want to sort it in descending order..

I mean the last line of document must be first line and vice versa

Pls let me know is there any function or snippet to achive this..

I'm not that good at php, Appreciate all responses irrespective of quality...Thank You

Comment: `file()` + `array_reverse()` + `implode()` + `file_put_contents()`

Answer (score 2):

use natsort() and than use function `array_reverse()`.

Also refer link 
[PHP Grab last 15 lines in txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570947/php-grab-last-15-lines-in-txt-file)
it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

[array_reverse](https://www.php.net/array_reverse) will give the contents in descending order

```
$reverse = array_reverse($array, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not the most efficient approach for a large text file, you could use [file](http://www.php.net/file), [array_reverse](http://www.php.net/array_reverse) and [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/file_put_contents) to achieve this as follows...

```
<?php
    // Fetch each line from the file into an array
    $fileLines = file('/path/to/text/file.txt');

    // Swap the order of the array
    $invertedLines = array_reverse($fileLines);

    // Write the data back to disk
    file_put_contents('/path/to/write/new/file/to.txt', $invertedLines);
?>
```

...to achieve what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

For longer files:

```php
<?php

function rfopen($path, $mode)
{
    $fp = fopen($path, $mode);
    fseek($fp, -1, SEEK_END);
    if (fgetc($fp) !== PHP_EOL) fseek($fp, 1, SEEK_END);
    return $fp;
}

function rfgets($fp, $strip = false)
{
    $s = '';
    while (true) {
        if (fseek($fp, -2, SEEK_CUR) === -1) { 
            if (!empty($s)) break;
            return false;
        }
        if (($c = fgetc($fp)) === PHP_EOL) break;
        $s = $c . $s;
    }
    if (!$strip) $s .= PHP_EOL;
    return $s;
}

$file = '/path/to/your/file.txt';

$src = rfopen($file, 'rb');
$tgt = fopen("$file.rev", 'w');

while ($line = rfgets($src)) {
    fwrite($tgt, $line);
}

fclose($src);
fclose($tgt);

// rename("$file.rev", $file);
```

Replace '/path/to/your/file.txt' with the path to your file.
Uncomment the last line to overwrite your file.