# fgetcsv open at specific row?

Tags: php

Is there a way to use fgetcsv to open on a particular row?

I have a really big csv and would like to run around 100 lines at a time via ajax. I can easily stop the while loop, but how would I open on a particular line? Or is this impossible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no simple way to start reading at row 100, but what you can do is read/set the position in the file like this:

```
$k = <previous position>;
fseek($file, $k);
while(...) {
   fgetcsv(...);
   ...
}
$k = ftell($file);   //new position
```

Now it's just a matter of preserving this position between page calls.

Comment: Cheaper to just use fgets() for the skipping part and save the overhead of CSV parsing, since that data's just being thrown away.

Comment: Cheaper than what?  I was thinking of skipping it with `fseek()` without reading at all.  `fgets()` will not work, since CSV file can include multi-line values, which `fgetcsv()` understands correctly, but `fgets()` would not.

Comment: Hmm. true enough. I really should remember to wake up first before working on an answer...

Comment: @AleksG can you give a complete example, we don't need to use fopen here?

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer doesn't seem to answer the actual the question. The posted question is how to open at a particular row.  The answer above is great way to save a spot and come back to it, but doesn't answer the question of opening/starting at a particular row.

I'm also searching for a nicer way to do this, so far here's what I have:

```
function parse_data($skip_rows = 0){
  $record_number = 0;
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 2000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if (++$record_number <= $skip_products) continue;
    // do work
  }
}
```

Works, but I'm sure there's a nicer way.

EDIT: found a similar question:  [How do I open a file from line X to line Y in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514673/how-do-i-open-a-file-from-line-x-to-line-y-in-php)

Better to use: [SplFileObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php)